# Can asymptotes be considered as common tangent to two branches of hyperbola?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

Today I was solving archive of jee advanced and I found a matrix question of 2008 regarding whether two branches of a hyperbola has a common tangent or not. The answer was no they don't. But then I  thought of asymptotes and it's definition everywhere comprises of the fact that it's a tangent at infinity to the hyperbola. And so now I'm a bit confused regarding the very definition of the hyperbola. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "tangent at infinity" is just a way of speaking. Unless you're doing some advanced topic like projective geometry, there is nothing at infinity, no place for the tangent to be tangent to the hyperbola.

Comment: I get that but then literally speaking what's the exact definition of asymptotes,mate?

Comment: "An asymptote is a line or curve that approaches a given curve arbitrarily closely," according to MathWorld, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptote.html Nothing there about "a tangent at infinity".

Comment: Are we OK now??

Comment: Yep, of course we are. I get it that it has nothing to do with tangents and it's a mere theoretical concept talking about a line in close proximity. But can you suggest me a case where it doesn't happens at infinity,(coz all the cases like lnx that come in my mind have infinity involved)?

Comment: Here's a link to a spiral asymptotic to a circle: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Asymptotic_circle_spiral.svg

Comment: Is a mathematical equation to such a curve even possible?

Comment: Yes, such curves come up naturally in the study of differential equations and dynamical systems. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle

Comment: Thanks mate you were a lot of help!!

Comment: Just drop an upvote if you believe that my answer is what you were tryin to explain me.

Comment: Close enough. Can't upvote, haven't finished signing up for my account. For future reference: if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 2):

In projective geometry, the two asymptotes are two lines tangent to the projective closure of the hyperbola (at two different points) whereas a common tangent is one line tangent to two different curves (at two different points). Projectively the hyperbola is just one curve as the circle is one curve.

To make this precise. In projective geometry we have $x^2-y^2=z^2.$ If we let $z=1$ we get $x^2-y^2=1$ which is a hyperbola in the affine plane.

[image: hypxy]

Now if we look at the line at infinity, $z=0,$ we get $x^2-y^2=0$ in the ${\Bbb P}^1$ or algebraically $k[x,y].$ This only means that in the affine $y=1$, $x=\pm 1$ or the curve $x^2-y^2=z^2$ intersects the line at infinity in two points: $(x:y:z)=(\pm 1:1:0).$ The asymptotes $x^2-y^2=0$ also intersect the line at infinity in these two points. To make things clearer we can look at the other two affines $x=1$ and $y=1$: $1^2-y^2=z^2$ and $x^2-1^2=z^2$ or $y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2-z^2=1.$ One is the circle and the other is a hyperbola like in the affine $z=1.$ Let's look closer at the circle: $y^2+z^2=1$ and the line $z=0.$ This is now just a line through the origin and intersects the circle in two diametrically opposite points: $(1:\pm 1:0).$ These are the same two points as before, projectively. Now look at the lines $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$ in the $z=1$ affine. In the $x=1$ affine these become $1+y=0$ and $1-y=0$ or the tangent lines $y=1$ at $(1:1:0)$ and $y=-1$ at $(1:-1:0)$ to $y^2+z^2=1.$

[image: hypyz]

Added: over the reals remember that ${\Bbb P}^2$ is not orientable.

Comment: (+1) Another benefit to thinking about tangents in a way that pays attention to ideal points (points at infinity) is that it rescues the idea of "a line is a tangent to a conic if it meets the conic in only one point" from problems like non-tangent lines parallel to the axis of a parabola or asymptotes of a hyperbola, since these also meet the conic at a second (ideal) point https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/tangents.html ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20220123180758/https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/tangents.html))

Answer (score 1):

An asymptote is a line that approaches a curve arbitrarily closely. Being a tangent at infinity is a mere misconception so we can say that we don't have any common tangent for a hyperbola.